# Youtube RSS feed

Tags: android, xml, youtube

Hi I’ve trying to implement a Youtube RSS feed into my application. I’m using this link http://m.youtube.com/#/profile?gl=GB&hl=en-GB&client=mv-vf-uk&user=RandomUser&safesearch=always but its limiting me to 25 videos. Does anyone know how to increase this size to include more videos?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not sure which url you are using, Have you tried giving max-results parameter and , start-index and last-index ? Those paramters are used by youtube api's to usually paginate the results.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football+-soccer&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=20&v=2

It's a different api though, which is well documented. You can find more about the api here.
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html